# AWS EC2 Creation doesn't get an IP address.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, launch

I have tried to create a new AWS EC2 instance off of an existing one, and I keep getting this after doing the final launch:

[image: EC2 Doesn't Assign IP]
So here are the steps:

1. From the AWS console stop the instance you are duplicating.
2. Create a snapshot of the instance.
3. Create a duplicate instance from the resulting snapshot and create a new Key Pair.
4. Launch the instance, go through the configuration, etc...

Would anyone know why it doesn't assign an IP address when I launch?

Brent.

Comment: Did you mean create an image of the instance in step 2 ? If yes, during step 4 on the configure instance details page, select a VPC from the list, the ‘Auto-Assign Public IP’ list is displayed select Enable to assign a public IP. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue would be your subnet (from your image: subnet-604ac10e).

1. Head over to your subnet page (from VPC), and check the box for that subnet to select; Click the "Actions" button at the top of the page, and select "Modify auto-assign IP settings".
2. In there, you'll see "Auto-assign IPv4"; check the box and save. Create a new instance in that subnet and save.

[image]